# Prism IContainerProvider - How may I resolve an unknown number of instances?

Tags: prism

I have a Prism WPF App (using Unity) that loads several modules each of which registers an object that implements a common interface.

At shutdown time, I want my app to be able resolve all the implementations of the interface that have been registered by all the loaded modules.

I realize I can have each module register a separate named instance, e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("registration1");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>("registration2");
```

But my app does not know about the strings "registration1" or "registration2" nor  does it care. It doesn't even know what modules will end up loading.   It just wants to get an instance of the interface and call a function.

Is there a way that I can ask `IContainerProvider` to "give me instances of every separate registration of IFoo" without knowing the names used to register them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can ask IContainerProvider to "give me instances of every separate registration of IFoo" without knowing the names used to register them?

If you use Unity as container, you can inject an `IFoo[]` and get all the named registrations or inject an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` to get all the named registrations *and* the default one.

Other containers may/will behave differently. Prism's container-wrapper doesn't promise any behavior, so you'll have to look into the documentation of your container.

Sidenote: it's not a good idea (most of the time) to actively ask the container, like calling `Resolve` or `ResolveAll`.

Comment: I am using Unity.  Guess I'll have to decide if using knowledge of the container is worth it.  So far I have avoided asking the container explicitly for anything.  In fairness I'm doing this literally inside the application class, derived from PrismApplication so I feel ***little*** less constrained there.  I guess I should ask, is this sort of "pattern" -- asking for all registrations -- something that IContainerProvider or unity was really designed for or just  hack.